# Is it possible to let the user authorize permissions in app instead when using AccountManager

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-play-services

I use AccountManager to get access token to authorize calls to Google Drive. When running this line of code:

```
mgr.blockingGetAuthToken(account, ApiConst.DRIVE_AUTH_SCOPE, true);
```

The user gets a notification whith permission requests. Is it possible to show this from the app and let the user accept the permissions? I know that if using Google Play Service i can catch an exception and extract an intent to use:

```
  try {
    return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
  } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(userRecoverableException.getIntent(), mRequestCode);
  }
```

Is there a similar way to achieve this when using AccountManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. If I use this method the user will be asked to accept permissions instead of getting a notification:

```
    am.getAuthToken (
            account.account,
            ApiConst.DRIVE_AUTH_SCOPE,
            options,
            this,
            new OnTokenAcquired(),
            null);
```

OnTokenAcquired is a class implementing AccountManagerCallback. In its run method you will get the token.